# Submit button returns to index page instead of sending data

Tags: forms, html, email

Here is the link for the website - http://zigzagadvertising.com.ph/aleemguiapal/97-2/

I have a problem regarding my forms in wordpress. Whenever i click on the submit button it returns to the index page instead of sending the data into an email address

**This is my PHP code which i placed on top of the Header.php. This code is placed before the  tag**

```
<?php 
$error=false;
$sent=false;
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
if(empty($_POST['firstname']) || empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['message'])) {
$error = true;
} else {

 $to = "clestcruz@gmail.com";

 $name = trim($_POST['firstname']);
 $email = trim($_POST['email']);
 $comments = trim($_POST['message']);

 $subject = "Contact Form";

 $messages = "Name: $firstname \r\n Email: $email \r\n Comments: $message";
 $headers = "From:" . $name;
 $mailsent = mail($to, $subject, $messages, $headers);

 if($mailsent){
     $sent= true;
}
}
}
?>
```

**And this is my custom page(Contact Page)**

```
<!--CONTACT-->
<div  class="container">
<div  class="eleven columns contact">
     <div id="contact-container" class="eleven columns alpha omega contact">
         <h2>contact us</h2>
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras non lacus vel nulla molestie cursus quis a urna. Donec sodales venenatis consequat. Sed tristique elit nec diam rhoncus adipiscing</p>
     </div>

     <div id="note-container" class="eleven columns alpha omega note">
         <p>All fields marked with an asterisk(<span class="asterisk">*</span>) are required</p>
     </div>

     <div class="contactform">
     <form id="register-form" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">


     <?php if($error == true) { ?>
     <p class="error"> There are some misisng fields.</p>
     <?php } if($sent == true) { ?>
     <p class="sent">Thank you for sending your message</p><?php } ?>


         <div class="four columns alpha contact-form">

         <label>prefix</label>
         <input type="text"  />
         <label><span class="asterisk">*</span>first name</label>
         <input type="text" name="firstname"/>
         <label><span class="asterisk"></span>middle name</label>
         <input type="text" name="middlename"/>
         <label><span class="asterisk"></span>last name</label>
         <input type="text" name="lastname"/>
         <label><span class="asterisk">*</span>email address</label>
         <input type="text" name="email"/>

        </div>

        <div class="four columns contact-form">

         <label>phone</label>
         <input type="text" />
         <label>street</label>
         <input type="text" />
         <label><span class="asterisk"></span>zip</label>
         <input type="text" name="zip" />
         <label><span class="asterisk"></span>city</label>
         <input type="text" name="city" />


        </div>

        <div class="clearfix"></div>

        <div class="eleven columns contact-form alpha omega">

        <label><span class="asterisk"></span>subject</label>
        <input type="text" name="subject"/>
        <label><span class="asterisk">*</span>message</label>
        <textarea name="message"></textarea>


        <input class="contact-button" type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
        <input class="contact-button" type="reset" value="reset" />

        </div>

     </form>
     </div>

<div class="four columns">
</div>

</div>



 <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
</div>   


<?php get_footer(); ?>



</body>
</html>
```

I tried making a contact page and uploaded it into a free hosting site and it seem to be working properly. I even got the data or values in the forms. Not sure if the reason why my forms is not working properly is because of wordpress itself.

Comment: use `wp_mail` function of wordpress for sending mail and install plugin `SMTP` for mail configuration and check whether its is working or not.

Answer (score 0):

Put `var_dump($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);` at the top of `header.php` and you will see the problem. That always points to `index.php` because nearly everything loads through `index.php`.

Use [`get_permalink`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink) to get the "apparent" URL and use that instead of `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` in the form action attribute.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can totally remove the form's action attribute. Wordpress will automatically post the form to the same url
2. If you have to put your code in your theme, add it to the custom page template that you've created for contact page, rather than adding it in header.php
3. If you are trying to send an email, use wordpress' built-in [wp_mail() function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_mail)